# Both synchronous, but why the NotificationQueue of function can "ignoring” duplicate notifications?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

Why NotificationQueue.PostingStyle.now can remove through coalescing, but NotificationCenter.default has no way of knowing whether more notifications are coming or not? Coalescing Notifications of the Notification Programming Topics say "its behavior is synchronous—notifications are posted before returning" and both its behavior is synchronous, so how can (why only) the enqueue(_ notification: Notification, postingStyle: NotificationQueue.PostingStyle, coalesceMask: NotificationQueue.NotificationCoalescing, forModes modes: [RunLoop.Mode]?) function knows notifications are coming?

I've both simply tested the invocation of the methods are synchronous: before the posting object can resume its thread of execution, it must wait until the notification center dispatches the notification to all observers and returns.
Does anyone has an answer to this? Any help will do. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think NotificationCenter is a very cool way of passing values in the observer mode.The notification center mechanism is so simple and convenient, that it’s tempting to let any and all objects, view controllers and models communicate with it.Thanks to Paulw11 for his answer, which deepened my understanding of the notification queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first paragraph of the `NotificationQueue` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationqueue) gives you a clue -

> Whereas a notification center distributes notifications when posted, notifications placed into the queue can be delayed until the end of the current pass through the run loop or until the run loop is idle. Duplicate notifications can be coalesced so that only one notification is sent although multiple notifications are posted.

A `NotificationQueue` can't coalesce notifications indefinitely, it can only do so until the end of the current run loop pass or until the run loop is idle.

Specifying `.now` for the posting style states that:

> The notification is posted immediately after coalescing.

Since you are delivering the notification immediately, it cannot coalesce with any notifications that haven't yet been enqueued, but it can coalesce any notifications that are still in the queue; Notifications enqueued with `.whenIdle` or `.asap` posting style.

Consider the following snippet:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .test, object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification) in
    print("Received notification")
}
    
let queue = NotificationQueue.default
    
queue.enqueue(Notification(name: .test), postingStyle: .now)
print("Posted")
queue.enqueue(Notification(name: .test), postingStyle: .now)
print("Posted")
queue.enqueue(Notification(name: .test), postingStyle: .now)
print("Posted")
```

This will print:

> Received notification
>
> Posted
>
> Received notification
>
> Posted
>
> Received notification
>
> Posted

Since the `postingStyle` of `.now` does not allow for any coaelscing.

Now, consider:

```
let queue = NotificationQueue.default
    
queue.enqueue(Notification(name: .test), postingStyle: .whenIdle)
print("Posted")
queue.enqueue(Notification(name: .test), postingStyle: .whenIdle)
print("Posted")
queue.enqueue(Notification(name: .test), postingStyle: .whenIdle)
print("Posted")
```

This will print:

> Posted
>
> Posted
>
> Posted
>
> Received notification

Since the three notifications can be coalesced before they are delivered when the run loop is idle.  You would see the same behaviour with `.asap`

Finally, consider:

```
queue.enqueue(Notification(name: .test), postingStyle: .whenIdle)
print("Posted")
queue.enqueue(Notification(name: .test), postingStyle: .whenIdle)
print("Posted")
queue.enqueue(Notification(name: .test), postingStyle: .now)
print("Posted")
```

This will print:

> Posted
>
> Posted
>
> Received notification
>
> Posted

The first two queued notifications can be coalesced with the final notification as they are still in the queue waiting for the run loop to be idle. The one notification will be delivered to the `NotificationCenter` immediately.

In summary, if you always use `.now` for the `postingStyle` then a `NotificationQueue` will behave essentially the same as posting the notification directly to the `NotificationCenter`, but if you use a different posting style then queued notifications may be coalesced to a single notification.